# Timeinterval Check if Database Connection exists every 3 minutes at the backend while application is running C#

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, database-connection, intervals

At the start of my application, I'm successfully able to check if SQL Server is running, if its not running start the specific service and then check if a particular database is connected. But I want to learn how to check if the database is connected at a timed interval.If the database gets disconnected i.e if the database gets deleted or renamed at the backend while application is running then the application should automatically terminate. How best I can achieve this?

How to call the Database is connected function at intervals? If its not connected it should terminate the application.

```
namespace CLearning
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool isServiceRunning = false;

            // Applying the required visual styles - we need to do it before we display any single form on the screen. 
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


            //Check specific SQL Server and database is running
            isServiceRunning = DataAccessContext.CheckSQLServiceStatus();

            if (isServiceRunning)
            {
                //SQL is running, checking for Local DB connection

                bool isLocalDAOConnected = DataAccessContext.CheckIsLocalDAOConnected();
                if (!isLocalDAOConnected)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "Database connection is not available on the machine. The application will termiante.",
                        "No database connection available",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }

                Application.Run(new Form1());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DataAccess class that checks if the server is running and database is connected is here

```
namespace CLearning.DataAccess
{
    public class DataAccessContext 
    {

        private static bool _isSQLServiceRunning = false;
        private static bool _isLocalDAOConnected = false;

        public static bool CheckSQLServiceStatus()
        {
          string myServiceName = "MSSQL$CLearning"; //service name of SQL Server Express
          string status; //service status (For example, Running or Stopped)

            //service status: For example, Running, Stopped, or Paused
            ServiceController mySC = new ServiceController(myServiceName);

            try
            {
                status = mySC.Status.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SQL Service not found. It is probably not installed, application will terminate. [exception=" + ex.Message + "]");
                return _isSQLServiceRunning;
            }
            //service status: For example, Running, Stopped, or Paused
            _isSQLServiceRunning = true;
            //if service is Stopped or StopPending, you can run it with the following code.
            if (mySC.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) | mySC.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))
            {
                try
                {
                    mySC.Start();
                    var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
                    mySC.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running,timeout);
                    _isSQLServiceRunning = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in starting the service: " + ex.Message);
                    _isSQLServiceRunning = false;
                }
            }
            return _isSQLServiceRunning;
        }

        public static bool CheckIsLocalDAOConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                GlobalConfig.Connection.TestConnection(); //SQL QUERY That checks for openning the connection
                return _isLocalDAOConnected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return _isLocalDAOConnected;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide.

Thanks
AA

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: BugFinder  I'm struggling how to check the connection status of database at the backend of the application at every 3 minutes. As soon as the connection fails then the application should terminate by displaying a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the database is available every three minutes?

From your status thread, do this every three minutes:

1. Open a connection to the database server.
2. Set the connection to nonblocking reads with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`
3. Do a raw query of the form `SELECT TOP 1 somecolumn FROM a_key_table;`
4. Close the connection.

Do all that stuff in a `try{}catch(){}` block. If you get an exception, your database has failed in the way that matters -- you can't read a row from one of your application's important tables.

The exception will tell you what went wrong (if you care): connection timeout, authentication failure, cannot read table, etc.

Comment: I'm able to check if connection timeout, authentication failure, cannot read table, etc. But how do I call this every few minutes just to check that the application is connected to the sql database? Basically I want the application to terminate if the database connection is lost.

Comment: Is your question about how to organize the three-minute part of doing the dbms connectivity test? Please, [edit] your question to explain exactly what part of the problem you can't figure out. Thanks.